# How to show Rows of Duplicate Entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to get only the rows that have duplicate entries in column `newcons`. In the result, I want to show the whole row with `recno` and `oldcons`, and against it `newCons` should appear. What SQL query can I use to do this?

Here is my Table:

```
RecNo OldB  OldCons    NewCons
1   01      0145501     0008000
2   01      0253801     0107400
3   01      0271200     0000500
4   01      0271201     0012000
5   01      0271202     0000200
6   01      0271300     0000800
7   01      0271301     0001100
8   01      0271302     0002000
9   01      0271303     0001000
10  01      0271304     0001000
```

This result should appear:

```
RecNo   OldBch  OldSdiv OldCons NewSdiv NewCons
9       01      14433   0271303 14433   0001000
10      01      14433   0271304 14433   0001000
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you a single row for each duplicate:

```
select * from tbl a join tbl b on a.newcons = b.newcons and a.recno > b.recno
```

To find the `NewCons` values that are duplicated:

```
select newcons from tbl group by newcons having count(*) > 1
```

Now, just nest that into a regular `SELECT`:

```
select * from tbl where newcons in (select newcons from tbl group by newcons having count(*) > 1)
```